# Server side streaming gRPC application significantly slows down when a client is connected

Tags: python, grpc, object-detection

I am running an object detecting neural network with a video input. Normally on my computer the process works at around 10 fps. I need to somehow serve the results of each frame to multiple clients on the network. I thought I would give gRPC a go. The problem is when a single client is connected, even without serving any messages, the performance drops to almost 0.01 fps. I believe each connection runs on it's own thread. What might be causing this issue?

Below is my service code.

Proto:

```
syntax = "proto3";

import "google/protobuf/empty.proto";

package coords;

service Location {
    rpc HelloServer(google.protobuf.Empty) returns (stream Result);
}


message Result {
    repeated Item item = 1;
}

message Item {
    int32 id  = 1;
    int32 team = 2;
    float coordx = 3;
    float coordy = 4;
}
```

My service:

```
class LocationService(pb2_grpc.LocationServicer):

    def __init__(self):
        self.last_message = None
        self.cnt = 0

    def HelloServer(self, message, context):

        lastcnt = 0

        while True:            
            while self.cnt > lastcnt:
                lastcnt = self.cnt
                yield self.last_message

    def AddMessage(self, message):
        self.last_message = message
        self.cnt += 1
```

Entry point:

```
try:
    if args.serve:
        server = grpc.server(futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=1000))
        pb2_grpc.add_LocationServicer_to_server(LocationService(), server)
        server.add_insecure_port('localhost:50051')
        server.start()
    
    run_detector(model, args)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    sys.exit()
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be caused by GIL: https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock

Python's Global Interpreter Lock prevents the parallel execution, so if there are multiple threads doing high-cpu tasks, the overall performance will degrade badly due to thread hops.

There are several solutions here:

1. `max_workers` means maximum number of threads, maybe tune it down helps. In gRPC's example, we recommend to use the default value (not setting it), see [CPython code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/concurrent/futures/thread.py#L136).
2. Since your usage is straight-forward, I would recommend to give asyncio a try. It constraints the serving logic to one thread, minimized the impact. Here is an example (you can find more in the neighboring folders): https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/examples/python/helloworld/async_greeter_server.py
3. If you are comfortable with profilers, you can use [pprof](https://github.com/google/pprof) and [perf](https://www.brendangregg.com/perf.html) to see what is using your process's CPU cycles. If you think there is space for improvement, feel free to contribute or file an issue to https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues

Comment: Thank you for the answer. At first I thought that protobuf was the problem and switched to messagepack over tcp, however the result was the same extremely slow performance. I removed the code related to messagepack and the problem persisted. I noticed when a client connects to my threaded tcp server, even when the server doesn't send or receive anything, the performance drops drammatically. I don't know why, but putting time.sleep(0.01) in the while loop of my client handler solved the problem.

Comment: This fix is mind blowing. If possible, please file a reproduction example to the gRPC issues. I would like to learn why. "time.sleep(0.01)" can be actively yielding to another thread. Are you using gRPC Python as inter-process communication?